# android:background killing Activity enter/return transitions

Tags: android, android-layout, android-animation

I always used Activity enter/return transitions (using xml transitions like slide and fade to animate views) and always worked because it's very straightforward. Now in my last project I was having problems even with dummy activites (without any real processing), the transitions simply don't work, so after hours of changing layout code, I figured out that the responsible is the `android:background` in root FrameLayout of Activity Layout where I set some background color. When I removed this attribute, the transitions came back to work. Also, if I apply this attribute only in activity theme, the transitions stop again.

Currently my project is only animating the second activity that only has this layout structure:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
   <ImageView>
   <RecyclerView>
</FrameLayout>
```

And the transition does slide in ImageView from top and slide in RecyclerView from bottom. But like I've said. It only works if the root FrameLayout don't have a background color.

Do you have any idea if it's a bug or anything else?

**EDIT:** If I use an ugly dummy view just to provide background color, the transitions work:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
   <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary" />

   <ImageView>
   <RecyclerView>
</FrameLayout>
```

**EDIT 2:** Same problem happens if I use another root ViewGroup like LinearLayout instead FrameLayout.

Comment: are you sure you are using valid color or valid drawable?

Comment: Yes, I'm using the colorPrimary of main app theme just for testing pourposes, and it's shows in app but the transition don't work.

Comment: can you provide piece of code how you set this color?

Comment: I've editted my question.

Comment: "FrameLayout is designed to block out an area on the screen to display a single item". Remove one item from framelayout and try it again.

Comment: Look at my new edition please.

Comment: In current state, you have 3 items in FrameLayout, either remove 2 of them or wrap them to LinearLayout (or RelativeLayout), so FrameLayout will hold one composite view.

Comment: But FrameLayout places child views in a stack way as RelativeLayout does and it's a behavior I'm expecting. Anyway I followed your suggestion (replace FrameLayout by LinearLayout) and the same problem happens if I set a background color to LinearLayout.

Comment: you are right (forget about stack feature), everytime I spot some strange behaviour like this, I try to reproduce problem with minimal code. In most situation there is some side-effect of seemingly non-related code, so start from scratch - create 2 empty activities, set them layout, where one of them will have layout as in your question and then send intent with transition effect.

Comment: I have already did this. I was using a new minimum project just to test it before asking here. And just to let you know, FrameLayout with just one child also have this background color issue.

Comment: @matoni I've found a workaround. Look at my own answer.

Answer (score 2):

I've found a solution (or workaround) using a friend tip:

if I use this attribute in root FrameLayout, the transition works:

```
android:transitionGroup="false"
```